# API to PocketPC Windows Mobile 6

Tags: compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5, pocketpc

I have a Ciperlab scanner running Windows Mobile 6 and developing with compact framework 3.5. I need to make a phone call and when the call is complete return to the program where the operator completes the transaction. I have used the Function PhoneMakeCall in the phone.dll but the resulting panel requires a number of buttons to be pressed. The perfect solution would be to hide the entire phone panel. Solutions from anyone who has done this before would be very welcome. I know the technology is old, but I am stuck with it as it comes with the scanner.

Answer (score 1):

To make a phone call, the Telephony API (TAPI) has to be used. This is an API provided by MS. Making a phone call requires many code lines and os it may be easier to use a wrapper like the OpenNetCF Telephony Compact Framwork Classes. [Here](http://programmaremobile.blogspot.de/2009/10/how-to-make-call-with-opennetcf-tapi.html) is an example. There are [other](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446543.aspx) examples on using TAPI.

There is only minor information about [TAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms899558.aspx) use availabe by MS.

Some device vendors offer special Phone SDKs to support there devices in accessing the phone by code. For example the Intermec WWAN Toolkit.

I would first go with openNetCF.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for info josef. It was great

The first link takes you to :

http://programmaremobile.blogspot.co.za/2009/10/how-to-make-call-with-opennetcf-tapi.html

This has links to OpenNetCf but here the Wrapper (OpenNETCF.Telephony.dll) has been removed. There is another link to http://tapi.codeplex.com/ which has the source code for the wrapper and some samples. The OpenNETCF.Telephony.dll is included in the zip file for the examples but this version requires a licence and also does not have all the methods used by the samples. I downloaded the zipped source code  and compiled it. It has some problems but works well.

I have one outstanding problem. To save battery I turn off the phone. It must be turned on 30 seconds before making a call otherwise the system drops into the phone raw panels.There is no status event informing that the GSM network has stabilised and a call can be make. At the moment I am using a timer but this not a clean solution.

I have attached my final code for reference:

```
In Declarations
Imports OpenNETCF.Telephony
Friend WithEvents tapi As Telephony
Friend WithEvents CellLine As Line
Friend WithEvents CellCall As [Call]
Public CellPhoneCoverage As Boolean = False
Shared CellCallState As Integer = 1

Private Function CreateCellLine() As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim dc As DeviceCapabilities
'Open Tapi
Try
  tapi = New Telephony
  tapi.Initialize()
  If tapi.NumberOfDevices > 0 Then
     Try
       For i = 0 To tapi.NumberOfDevices - 1
         tapi.GetDeviceCapabilities(i, dc)
         If (dc.MediaModes And MediaMode.InteractiveVoice) = _ 
                MediaMode.InteractiveVoice Then
            'found the cellular line
            CellLine = tapi.CreateLine(i, dc.MediaModes, _ 
                 CallPrivilege.None)                                     
            'To save battery turn off phone. 
            'Note that it must be turned on for 30 seconds 
            ' before making a call otherwise we drop into the 
            ' phone raw panels
            NativeMethods.lineSetEquipmentState(CellLine.hLine, _ 
                      EquipmentState.Minimum)
            CreateCellLine = True

            'if battery is not an issue then check phone state
            'Dim es As EquipmentState
            'Dim rs As RadioState
            'NativeMethods.lineGetEquipmentState(CellLine.hLine, es, rs)
            'CreateCellLine = (es = EquipmentState.Full And rs = RadioState.On)
            Exit Function
         End If
       Next
       MsgBox("cell line not found")
       CreateCellLine = False
     Catch ex As Exception
         CreateCellLine = False
          MsgBox("CreateCellLine(1):" & ex.Message)
     End Try
  End If
Catch ex As Exception
  CreateCellLine = False
  MsgBox("CreateCellLine(2):" & ex.Message)
End Try
End Function

Handle events:
Private Sub CellCall_CallState(ByVal [call] As OpenNETCF.Telephony.Call, _
            ByVal state As OpenNETCF.Telephony.CallState) _ 
            Handles CellCall.CallState
 'Note that this state change is not called for disconencted and connected events
  MsgBox("Call state is " & state.ToString())
End Sub

Private Sub CellCall_Connected(ByVal [call] As OpenNETCF.Telephony.Call, _
            ByVal state As OpenNETCF.Telephony.CallState) _ 
            Handles CellCall.Connected
  MsgBox("Connected")
End Sub

Private Sub CellCall_Disconnected(ByVal [call] As OpenNETCF.Telephony.Call, _
            ByVal state As OpenNETCF.Telephony.CallState) _ 
            ByVal disconnectMode As OpenNETCF.Telephony.DisconnectMode) _
            Handles CellCall.Disconnected
  MsgBox("Disconnected")
End Sub

In the form_load procedure:
   'Open Tapi and check we have cell phone coverage
   CellPhoneCoverage = CreateCellLine()

To make a call:
   'If the phone if off then it must be turned on for 30 seconds 
   ' before making a call otherwise we drop into the phone raw panels

   Dim rc As Integer
   Dim es As EquipmentState
   Dim rs As RadioState
   NativeMethods.lineGetEquipmentState(CellLine.hLine, es, rs)
   If Not (es = EquipmentState.Full) Then
     rc = NativeMethods.lineSetEquipmentState(CellLine.hLine, EquipmentState.Full)
   Else
     If (es = EquipmentState.Full And rs = RadioState.On) Then
        CellCall = CellLine.MakeCall("0812500163", 27, False)
     End If
   End If

To end a call:
   CellCall.Hangup()
   If Not ((CellCallState = OpenNETCF.Telephony.CallState.Idle) Or _ 
           (CellCallState = OpenNETCF.Telephony.CallState.Disconnected)) Then
     'must do check otherwise get a null exception
     Try
       CellCall.Hangup()
       Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox("CellCall.Hangup: " & ex.Message)
     End Try
   End If

   'if battery is not an issue then leave phone on
   ' remember when making a call allow time for the network to connect
   ' otherwise we drop into the phone raw panels
   NativeMethods.lineSetEquipmentState(CellLine.hLine, _
                 EquipmentState.Minimum)
```